# React Linting, Missing file extension for "react" (import/extensions)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint, lint

I am using the Airbnb lint settings for my react app

and the line

```
import React from 'react';
```

Gives the error

**Missing file extension for "react" (import/extensions)**

Any idea how to fix this?

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "firebase": "^4.6.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.1",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^1.0.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "sass": "sass --watch src/styles/scss:src/styles/css",
    "sass:build": "sass src/styles/scss:src/styles/css"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of the airbnb settings and linter ? Please provide your package.json.

Comment: Post your package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `rules` object of your `.eslintrc` set `"import/extensions"` to `never` or `0` to avoid this.

Comment: This will lost the ```import/extensions``` lint feature at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if you have `eslint-plugin-import` installed, Airbnb style guide configuration uses it to handle linting of imports and exports. If you don't have it, it results in the error `Unable to resolve path to module '_module-name_'` and/or `Missing file extension for "_module-name_" (import/extensions)`.

Also since you have it installed in dev-dependencies, you can run something like `./node_modules/.bin/eslint .` or setup eslint globally to just run `eslint .`